# Is there a way to get a reference to a scene object's prefab?

Tags: unity-game-engine

During gameplay, is there any way to check whether a game object is an instance of a prefab, and get a reference to that prefab?  I tried various methods in `PrefabUtility`, but they're all saying that my scene's instance of a prefab is not a prefab.

Comment: doesnt seem very helpful but, the "(clone)" at the end of the gameobject's name means its an instance of a prefab. The name of the gameobject with out the last "(clone)" string, should lead you to the prefab the instance was cloned from

Comment: @rustyBucketBay Thanks for the suggestion; I could do that for dynamically instantiated prefabs, but I also want to know this for objects that are part of my scene's saved hierachy, and since those are not instantiated during gameplay, they don't have "(clone") in the name.

Comment: I was going to suggest https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.IsOutermostPrefabInstanceRoot.html but as @derHugo says that only works on editor. I once missed this feature in runtime, but up to what I reserached, it would be needed to be coded by one self, keeping references to the parent instantiated prefabs before parenting them into the scene somehow. I will follow this question in case threre's a way to achieve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that `PrefabUtility` like e.g. [`PrefabUtility.IsPartOfAnyPrefab`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.IsPartOfAnyPrefab.html) is in the `UnityEditor` namespace. So anyway it won't help you unless you need it only inside the UnityEditor itself.

Also [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/test-if-prefab-is-an-instance.562900/) might be relevant if the `PrefabUtility` isn't working for you in the Editor because you are in the prefab mode:

> In Prefab Mode the GameObject are simply regular gameobjects unless you have a nested prefab.

---

For runtime in a build or as soon as you enter the PlayMode **the concept of prefab instance doesn't really exist anymore**. They are then only `GameObject`s with no information about where they came from ;)

---

You could however store the reference to the prefab in a component like e.g.

```c#
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class PrefabInfo : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject original;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    private void Awake()
    {
        // See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.GetCorrespondingObjectFromOriginalSource.html
        original = PrefabUtility.GetCorrespondingObjectFromOriginalSource(gameObject);
    }
#endif
}
```

and on runtime also do

```c#
var obj = Instantiate(yourPrefab);
if(obj.TryGetComponent<PrefabInfo>(out prefabInfo)
{
    prefabInfo.original = yourPrefab.gameObject;
}
else
{
    obj.AddComponent<PrefabInfo>().original = yourPrefab.gameObject;
}
```

This way you would know if something is a prefab instance on runtime and which is the original prefab.

---

If you want to kind of hack this in order to automate it you could even create an Inspector for all `MonoBehaviour` and attach the `PrefabInfo` component automatically if something is a prefab or a prefab instance ;)

Comment: Tested - both result in false during runtime

Comment: @TomaszJuszczak oh yeah misread it ... this is returning true only if the object **is** a prefab .. not an instance of one ;)

Comment: @derHugo Good point about `PrefabUtility` being part of the `UnityEditor` namespace.  I hadn't thought of that problem.

Comment: @BenRubin I added a way how I think you could store the reference from within the UnityEditor. You would ofcourse have to make sure that your according prefabs and instances have that `PrefabInfo` class attached

Comment: @derHugo Thank you, that'll be very helpful.

Comment: They are not "regular", gameObjects, because regular gameObjects belong to some scene and are visible.

Answer (score 2):

**No** - the information is removed from the instantiated GameObjects in the runtime for performance reasons.

The only way to do this would be to store it yourself via Editor script, run it before you enter the runtime, map out all prefabs that are interesting to you, and use this newly created information.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion about storing the prefab in an Editor script.  I think I'll do that.